# Spring Cloud Gateway - Refreshing routes

Tags: spring-cloud

Using spring-cloud-gateway 2.0.0.M5, Im defining routes in configuration file (application.yml). I'm trying to update these routes by calling POST /application/gateway/refresh.

Modified routes, or new routes, are not refreshed, even though I see (with a breakpoint) that a refresh routine is actually executed.

Is the refresh supposed to work when routes are defined in configuration files ? Something I am missing ?

The use case would be routes defined in spring config server.

Comment: it is supposed to work. likely a bug.

Comment: The mechanic seems to be there, but ultimately the same GatewayProperties object gets re-loaded. What i will try: post to /env endpoint to force reloading of @ConfigurationProperties (GatewayProperties) and then post to /application/gateway/refresh. Maybe this is the way it is expected to work ?

Answer (score 5):

For those struggling with the same issue, here is a setup which works with 2.0.0.M5:

1. Routes configuration in application.yml file hosted in Spring Cloud Config Server (2.0.0.M7)
2. Add/Delete/Modify routes in application.yml
3. POST /actuator/refresh --> this will reload the routes definitions
4. POST /application/gateway/refresh --> this will reload the routes
5. Try new routes