# Spring cloud gateway refresh with RewritePath fails

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud-gateway

I'm running a spring cloud gateway instance that relies on spring cloud configuration server. My application starts up with the given following configuration.

```
  cloud:
    gateway:
      routes:
        - id: route-foo
          uri: lb://foo
          predicates:
            - Path=/api/foo/**
          filters:
            - name: RewritePath
              args:
                regexp: "/api/foo/(?<remaining>.*)"
                replacement: "/${remaining}"
```

Say I make a modification to my configuration and add an additional route below

```
        - id: route-bar
          uri: lb://bar
          predicates:
            - Path=/api/bar/**
          filters:
            - name: RewritePath
              args:
                regexp: "/api/bar/(?<remaining>.*)"
                replacement: "/${remaining}"
```

Executing a POST to `http://localhost:8080/actuator/refresh` returns the following error.

```
500 Server Error for HTTP POST &#34;/actuator/refresh&#34; (Encoded)
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'remaining' in value "/${remaining}"
    at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.parseStringValue(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:178)
```

It appears that spring is trying to parse my RewritePath replacement and substitute it with environment variables. What are my options?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're running into spring trying to replace variables in your configuration.

There are two solutions

### Escape the replacement syntax (Preferred)

change `replacement: "/${remaining}"`

to     `replacement: "/$\\{remaining}"`

The [RewriteGatewayFilterFactory](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-gateway/blob/2.2.x/spring-cloud-gateway-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/gateway/filter/factory/RewritePathGatewayFilterFactory.java#L61) does a replace on the configuration before running the filter.

### Enable ignoreUnresolvableNestedPlaceholders

```
@Bean
@Primary
public StandardReactiveWebEnvironment standardReactiveWebEnvironmentCustomizer(StandardReactiveWebEnvironment environment) {
    environment.setIgnoreUnresolvableNestedPlaceholders(true);
    return environment;
}
```

This will leave all unresolvable placeholders alone in your configuration and not fail during the refresh. I would recommend against this approach as it may end up delaying some issues into runtime if you're relying on a field to be populated correctly.

Theoretically you should be able to accomplish this same functionality with the [PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-context/src/main/java/org/springframework/context/support/PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.java), I had a hard time getting that to cooperate.

Comment: For finishing up the configuration refresh, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48287444/spring-cloud-gateway-refreshing-routes